# weird behaviour when working with double pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need help to understand why in this little program i cannot manipulate correctly pointers:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
          void change(char *s[][15]){
              int i=0;
              while(i<5){
                  if(s[i][0]=='B') s[i][0]='v';
                  i++;
              }
          }
    /*My code is supposed to allocate dynamically 5 arrays of 15 chars each
    (like tab[5][15])and then put a message on them and try to modify the messages.
In this particular case i'm trying to change the first letter of each string to 'V'.
    I'm doing this little experience because of another program 
    in which i have difficulties accessing double arrays*/    
    int main(){
            int i;
            char **s;
            s =malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
            for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                s[i]=malloc(15*sizeof(char));
                sprintf(s[i],"Bonjour%d",i);
            }
            change(s);
            for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                printf("%s\n",s[i]);
            }
            return 0;
    }
```

I was expecting :

```
Vonjour0
Vonjour1
Vonjour2
Vonjour3
Vonjour4
```

but I get :

```
Bonjour0
Bonjour1
Bonjour2
Bonjour3
Bonjour4
```

I'm testing this little code for another program and I don't get why the arrays don't change.
In my other program I can't access the double pointer or print the content.
so my question is : why in this program I can't modify the content of the arrays ?

Comment: if `s[i][0]` is a pointer, why are you comparing it to `B`, which is `char`? and assigning `v` to it?

Comment: they are  incompatible pointer, try `void change(char **s)`

Comment: Cornelle, Remember, when you allocate memory dynamically, you are responsible for tracking it and **freeing** it when it is no longer needed. (get it the habit of coding your `free` at the time of `malloc`). Also, you know to **validate** that each allocation succeeds. E.g. `if(!(s = malloc ( 5 * sizeof *s))) ...throw error..` While you can `sizeof (type)` you are better off `sizeof *s` and `sizeof **s` that prevents any potential for error in type choice. (of course you must dereference properly) Also compare `calloc` with `malloc`, it has distinct advantages in certain instances.

Comment: thanks , i'll keep it in my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your change method needs to use "char** s" instead of char *s[][15].  This is because your method is expecting a pointer to a multi-dimensional array.  This is immutable as a result, since your original data type for the string is a pointer to an array of strings (IE: An array of chars).

Hopefully that was clear.

Comment: I've made the change , but same result

Comment: What are your compiler options?  This seems to work fine for me.  See http://ideone.com/dqgxNm

Comment: I'm using codeblocks 13.12 (the latest ) and didn't change the default options

Comment: I am unable to get this issue to duplicate at all.  This may be an issue with codeblocks, though I'm skeptical.  Can you verify that the only change you've made is to your change method?

Comment: My bad , i've made a little mistake by keeping [ ][ ].Now it works.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
char **change(char **s){
              int i=0;
              while(i<5){
                  if(s[i][0]=='B') s[i][0]='v';
                  i++;
              }
              return s;
          }
```

Comment: I've made the change , but same result

Comment: I just compiled your code in my way the output was perfect

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change the function argument to `char *s[]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void change(char *s[]){
    int i=0;
    while(i<5){
        if(s[i][0]=='B') s[i][0]='v';
        i++;
    }
}

int main(){
    int i;
    char **s;
    s =malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        s[i]=malloc(15*sizeof(char));
        sprintf(s[i],"Bonjour%d",i);
    }
    change(s);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%s\n",s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
vonjour0
vonjour1
vonjour2
vonjour3
vonjour4
```