# Making int foo(int bar[][N]) work with int ** baz

Tags: c, syntax, casting

I have a function with the following prototype:

```
int foo(int bar[][N]);
```

And I want to send to it the variable `int ** baz` which is an array of the same size, only it was allocated.

I tried to explicitly cast and call `foo()` like so: `foo((int(*)[N])baz);` and it silenced the errors from the compiler but all the values in `baz` became junk when in `foo()` (why did it happen btw?).

Is there a way to do this without duplicating the same function and changing it's prototype?

`baz` was allocated like so:

```
int ** baz = (int**)malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        baz[i] = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: how `baz` was allocated?

Comment: and here is your problem, you need to do `int **baz = (int**)malloc(N*N*sizeof(int));` instead of malloc and then another malloc in loop

Comment: @Lashane why `N*N`? it's a 2d array.

Comment: right, it is 2d array and 2d array contains N*N elements, but you're allocating 1d array size of N with pointers to another arrays

Comment: Here is a similar recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129048/weird-behaviour-when-working-with-double-pointers/30129401

Comment: @Lashane what do you mean by malloc in a loop?

Comment: @kuhaku you have 3 lines of code: 1. malloc 2. loop 3. malloc in loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate baz like

```
int ( *baz )[N] = malloc( N * N * sizeof( int ) );
```

In this case there is no problem to call function

```
int foo(int bar[][N]);
```

with argument `baz`.

Taking into account your comment then the function that allocates a two-dimensional array dynamically and returns a pointer to it can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N   10

typedef int ( *PTR )[N];

PTR allocate( int n );

int ( *allocate( int n ) )[N]
{
    int ( *p )[N] = malloc( n * sizeof( *p ) );

    return p;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    free( allocate( N ) );

    return 0;
}
```

I showed two ways of the declaration of the function.

Comment: Is this type `int (*)[N]`? I mean what type do I return if I want to return `baz` from a function?

Comment: @kuhaku There are two approaches. Either you will declare a typedef as for example typedef int ( *PTR )[N]; (you can use any identifier instead of PTR) and use this typedef name as the return type. Or you can explicitly write the original return type as for example int ( *f() )[N];

Comment: Oh pretty neat with the typedef. It's the first time I see a function's prototype wrapped like this. Thanks for explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

The type `int **` is not compatible with the type `int (*)[N]` (which is what the type of your function argument resolves to).  The former is a pointer to pointer to `int`.  The latter is a pointer to an array of `N` `int`s.

It is very important to understand at this point that arrays are **not** pointers.  An array is a contiguous block of some number of elements of the same type.  In most contexts, including when they appear as function arguments, the values of expressions having array type are automatically *converted* to pointers (to the array's first element), but that's a whole different thing than array objects *being* pointers.  This distinction is a frequent source of confusion, but it is essential to understand when an array is a member of an aggregate type, such as a structure, union, or higher-dimensional array.

If you want to dynamically allocate an M x N array that you can pass to your function, then that looks like this:

```
int (*baz)[N] = malloc(M * sizeof(*baz));
```

If you want to pass your existing pointer pointer to your function, then the function should have this prototype:

```
int foo(int **bar);
```

Comment: I suppose many people will be confused about `arrays are not pointers`, as very many C text books say opposite `array (variable) is pointer to first element`. And in most of the cases these books are correct, though it takes some time to understand difference between array of pointers to arrays and 2d array.

Comment: @Lashane, I suppose people who stumble over "arrays are not pointers" are *already* confused.  You are probably right that there will be many such people, and that many of them will have gotten that way through reading texts and tutorials.  Any book that equates arrays with pointers, though, is at best oversimplifying.

Comment: @JohnBollinger An edit suggestion.... While technically correct (and in fact, exactly matching what the OP asked for), I think your answer may be misleading to a noob. It would be better to describe allocation of an M x N array and show that as "`int (*baz)[N] = malloc(M * sizeof(*baz));`" since the "`sizeof(*baz)`" part already includes the N dimension given in the declaration.  Apart from that, I like your answer better.